# Angular 12 app Azure app service (windows) not rendering any CSS. Works fine locallay

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am struggling with an issue in my Angular 13 app. When I deploy it to my windows based azure app service, it doesn't seem to render ANY sort of CSS. This particular app uses tailwinds as the CSS "engine".

The odd thing is that it was working in Azure. I did a couple of minor enhancements, did an ng build and copied the code to my dev app service in Azure, and now its not rending correctly at all...seems to be missing the CSS. I attached a couple screen shots of the home login/page (one working and one not working).

I inspected the page load, and there are no 404 errors. I have ran into some MIME type issues in the past, so I added those to my web.config with no luck.

I even rolled back the code to the previously working source code base and deployed it...and now it is having the same rending issue. This tells me that it might be a configuration item in my azure app service. It was working as of last night and I broke something and can't figure it out.

Any ideas as to where I could look? Thank you!

Eric

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you see your deployed css files via the kudu console? Is the url path for css framed by browser is correct (check in browser dev tools).

Comment: I did check dev tools, but don't see anything sticking out. I would think it would show some 404 errors if the paths were wrong. Everything seems in tact. Its almost like ng build isn't creating all the bundles properly.  

I started this app using a template called Fuse (to save some time). It is built on angular 13 and uses Tailwinds Css. It seems like all the tailwinds stuff is missing when I compile it....not sure how that could be. The only changes I made between the 2 version was I added single sign on via Okta...so I added their packages. That is when it all blew up on deployment.

Comment: I figured it out...it was along the lines of what I mentioned. This template stopped building "fully" when I used ng build. When I called ng build fuse, that worked! Not sure why it changed. fuse is the default project, so I figured it would build that with plain ole ng build.  Sometimes its better to build from the ground up instead of templates I guess because things can go sideways easily if you are not paying attention when adding in additional packages. Anand got me thinking about it instead of the obvious paths of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [User Anand Sowmithiran - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran) and [User Eric Elliston - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142875/eric-elliston). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

> The template stopped building "fully" while using `ng build`. By calling  `ng build fuse`, it started working. Sometimes it’s better to build from the ground up instead of templates because things can go sideways easily if you are not paying attention when adding in additional package.

References: [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)  and [Deploy Angular 8+ Application to Azure App Service(PaaS) using Local Git(CD) | by Drexsolo | Medium](https://medium.com/@kevinding0218/deploy-angular-8-application-to-azure-app-service-paas-using-local-git-cd-10d32f6f8629)